# Stripe Installation failed in react native android

Tags: android, react-native, stripe-payments

I am trying to install the stripe SDK for the stripe payment gateway. I have the provider for the stripe in my **App.js** with the publishable key. When I  try to run the android its build fails with the following error

> Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction

I have tried some solutions available online but nothing seems to work.

Here is my build.gradle file

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter() {
            content {
                includeModule("com.yqritc", "android-scalablevideoview")
            }
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of `stripe-react-native` is using `compileSdkVersion` 31, please check if your Android project is using the same `compileSdkVersion`, otherwise you might want to update your project's `compileSdkVersion` or use an older version of `stripe-react-native`

Comment: I have set compileSdkVersion to 31 but still no working

Comment: Can you share the build.gradle file and the full error message?

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
   > There was a failure while executing work items
      > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
         > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:

Comment: This is the error and I have edited the build.gradle file to my question

Comment: Your gradle configuration is almost same as mine, except the               
 includeModule("com.yqritc", "android-scalablevideoview"). Is there any reason you can't use implementation keyword to add this dependency?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using compileSdkVersion 29 you can use

"@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.1.2"

its work for me

```
npm i @stripe/stripe-react-native@0.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside /android/gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```